# Navigation Property not loading when only the ID of the related object is populated

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship, navigation-properties

I am trying to establish a many-to-one relationship. The entity that represents the “many” has a navigation property pointing back to the parent entity. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Key Field for all entities
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Date entity was created
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Last date Modified
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// keep track of Row Version used for concurrency
    /// </summary>
    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

}

public abstract class Document : BaseEntity
{
    #region Primitive Properties   


    /// <summary>
    /// Boolean value to determine if Document is in an active state
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Document comments and information
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FK back to User who owns document
    /// </summary>
    //public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }

    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation Back to User who owns document
    /// </summary>
    public User Owner { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Project : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyCode CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> TeamMembers { get; set; }

    #endregion
}    

 public class Rfi : Document
 {
    public string Number { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties

    //This points back to a Project Entity
    public virtual Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

So, when I insert the above entity, I am passing the ProjectId from the application into the Rfi entity (not the entire Project entity). Everything saves fine. The issue I am having is, when I pull the Rfi object back out of the database, the ProjectId is being populated, but the Project entity is null. I am using Lazy Loading, by default. Do I need to specify a navigation property on the Project entity, too? I don’t really want to. Unless, I can perform a mapping on my Rfi to accomplish this.

Update:
I assumed EF 4.1 would load my objects for me, but it seems, sometimes I need to explicitly include what objects I want to load. I am not entirely sure why. I am using a repository to query my entities. Here is the method I used to query the Rfi object:

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
       return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    }
```

What I ended up doing, in my Service layer I call it like this:

```
public Rfi FindByNumber(string number)
{
     var rfi = rfiRepository.GetQuery(r => r.Number == number).Include(r => r.Project).Single;
     return rfi
}
```

Comment: How does the `Project` and the `Document` class look? You don't need necessarily a navigation property on the other side. What you are describing should normally work. The problem is probably hidden in the other classes or any additional mapping.

Comment: I updated the code samples. Document is derived from the BaseEntity type.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? I think `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` doesn't work with a `Guid` in SQL Server (it's not Identity in the DB although the model allows this setting). But this is probably not the reason for your problem. Does eager loading with `Include` of the `Project` property work?

Comment: I am using SQL server and it works.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it was limitation in EF 1. Since EF 4 it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the mapping I created for the proeprty was creating a duplicate ID in the database. I had, for example, `ProjectId` and `Project_ID` in the database. I was populating `ProjectId` when a new item was saved to the context, but the `_ID` was not being populated. This is what EF 4.1 is using to relate the data. In my mapping I was tring to set the Project so it would not `CascadeOnDelete`. This is what my mapping looks like:

```
HasOptional(rfi => rfi.Project)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This mapping was creating 2 IDs in the database. Once I removed the mapping everything was working. I just need to figure out the correct mapping so I can remove the `CascadeOnDelete`, make the property optional, and only have one ID.

I figured if out with the Help of [EF Power Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx). You can reverse engineer your DB into POCOs. I changed the above line to:

```
HasOptional(r => r.Project)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.ProjectId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Even with a fluent interface mappings are a bit difficult to master. To understand how relationships are mapped in EF I created a simple database with my tables and foreign key assignments. I then used the Power Tools’ option for reverse engineering code first. Brilliant!

Answer (score 13):

You must make your navigation properties `virtual` for Lazy Loading to work.

While this makes sense implementation-wise, EF's strategy of ignoring the problem and just returning `null` is a terrible design decision.

NHibernate, on the other hand, by default doesn't let you use classes that don't have all of their properties virtual.

To avoid this problem, I wrote a test that verifies every reference property is marked as virtual. That way I find out immediately, instead of dealing with strange bugs down the road.

---

You can also try specifying the FK/Navigation properties explicitly:

```
public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
```

Comment: They are? If you look at my Rfi object the properties are set to virtual.

Comment: @DDiVita: Oh, I saw some properties that weren't (Owner, Comments) and didn't actually check `Project`. Try making those virtual, and check my last edit too.

Comment: While wasn't your problem, I've been scratching my head all day over why I was getting nulls back and this answer reminded me - virtual was missing in one class! So simple to forget and nothing warns you. I've had a number of struggles with an MVC project and all have been one line, if not one word fixes due to something obscure you need to remember.