# How to reference an object in your view model using EF 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3` and `Entity Framework 4.1 code first`.

I have the following defined in my database context class:

```
public class HefContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<GrantApplication> GrantApplications { get; set; }
   public DbSet<MaritalStatusType> MaritalStatusTypes { get; set; }
}
```

My MaritalStatusType class:

```
public class MaritalStatusType : IEntity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In my view model I have the following:

```
public class GrantApplicationDetailsViewModel
{
   public int MaritalStatusTypeId { get; set; }
   public MaritalStatusType MaritalStatusType { get; set; }
}
```

View code to display the marital status type name:

```
<tr>
   <td><label>Marital Status:</label></td>
   <td>@Model.MaritalStatusType.Name</td>
</tr>
```

In my controller's action method I get the grant application object by id.  It has a marital status type id from the grant application table.  I then map the grant application object to my GrantApplicationDetailsViewModel.  That's fine.  But when I want to specify the name of the marital status type in my view then it gives me errors, `object not set to an instance of an object`.  How would I get this to work?

Comment: You need to make sure your navigation property in GrantApplication is annotated properly and is loaded during query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144163/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-navigation-property-not-loading-when-only-the-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the virtual property in my grant application object and now it seems to work just fine.

```
public class GrantApplication : IEntity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int MaritalStatusTypeId { get; set; }
   public virtual MaritalStatusType MaritalStatusType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah from what ive heard its recommanded to put all your variables virtual. This is intended for EF.